# Regex: How to match sequence of key-value pairs at end of string

Tags: python, regex, key-value

I am trying to match key-value pairs that appear at the end of (long) strings. The strings look like (I replaced the "\n")

```
my_str = "lots of blah
          key1: val1-words
          key2: val2-words
          key3: val3-words"
```

so I expect matches "key1: val1-words", "key2: val2-words" and "key3: val3-words".

- The set of possible key names is known.
- Not all possible keys appear in every string.
- At least two keys appear in every string (if that makes it easier to match).
- val-words can be several words.
- key-value pairs should only be matched at the end of string.
- I am using Python re module.

I was thinking

```
re.compile('(?:tag1|tag2|tag3):')
```

plus some look-ahead assertion stuff would be a solution. I can't get it right though. How do I do?

Thank you.

/David

Real example string:

```
my_str = u'ucourt métrage pour kino session volume 18\nThème: O sombres héros\nContraintes: sous titrés\nAuthor: nicoalabdou\nTags: wakatanka productions court métrage kino session humour cantat bertrand noir désir sombres héros mer medine marie trintignant femme droit des femmes nicoalabdou pute soumise\nPosted: 06 June 2009\nRating: 1.3\nVotes: 3'
```

EDIT:

Based on Mikel's solution I am now using the following:

```
my_tags = ['\S+'] # gets all tags
my_tags = ['Tags','Author','Posted'] # selected tags
regex = re.compile(r'''
    \n                     # all key-value pairs are on separate lines
    (                      # start group to return
       (?:{0}):            # placeholder for tags to detect '\S+' == all
        \s                 # the space between ':' and value
       .*                  # the value
    )                      # end group to return
    '''.format('|'.join(my_tags)), re.VERBOSE)
```

regex.sub('',my_str) # return my_str without matching key-vaue lines
regex.findall(my_str) # return matched key-value lines

Comment: Are the key-val-Pairs really just separated by a space-character? Better give a real example (maybe just the last 100 chars).

Comment: What does "key-value pairs should only be matched at the end of string" mean if val3-words can be an arbitrarily long string?

Comment: @phynfo, I checked the raw data, there are actually line breaks which may make this easier. See my edited post.
@Janne It means that starting from the end of the string I want to match all the consecutive "key: val-words" pairs I can find, where key is from a predetermined set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The negative zero-width lookahead is `(?!pattern)`.

It's mentioned part-way down the [re module documentation page](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

`(?!...)`

> Matches if ... doesn’t match next. This is a negative lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?!Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s not followed by 'Asimov'.

So you could use it to match any number of words after a key, but not a key using something like `(?!\S+:)\S+`.

And the complete code would look like this:

```
regex = re.compile(r'''
    [\S]+:                # a key (any word followed by a colon)
    (?:
    \s                    # then a space in between
        (?!\S+:)\S+       # then a value (any word not followed by a colon)
    )+                    # match multiple values if present
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

matches = regex.findall(my_str)
```

Which gives

```
['key1: val1-words ', 'key2: val2-words ', 'key3: val3-words']
```

If you print the key/values using:

```
for match in matches:
    print match
```

It will print:

```
key1: val1-words
key2: val2-words
key3: val3-words
```

Or using your updated example, it would print:

```
Thème: O sombres héros 
Contraintes: sous titrés 
Author: nicoalabdou 
Tags: wakatanka productions court métrage kino session humour cantat bertrand noir désir sombres héros mer medine marie trintignant femme droit des femmes nicoalabdou pute soumise 
Posted: 06 June 2009 
Rating: 1.3 
Votes: 3
```

You could turn each key/value pair into a dictionary using something like this:

```
pairs = dict([match.split(':', 1) for match in matches])
```

which would make it easier to look up only the keys (and values) you want.

More info:

- [Python re module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)
- [Python Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#regex-howto)
- [Perl Regular Expression Reference "perlreref"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html)

---

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the solution and the explanation, is there a way to limit the possible keys to a set of words? Something like (?:tag1|tag2|tag3) instead of [\S]+ for example? But I think the solution as it is will work fine.