# Regex: Negative Lookaheads for key-value parsing

Tags: python, regex, parsing, key-value, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to work on the following response header:

```
Start-Time: 11111.11 Content-type: foo/bar; charset=utf-8 End-Time: 22222.22
```

and would like to retrieve:

```
'Start-Time 11111.11',
'Content-type foo/bar; charset=utf-8',
'End-Time 22222.22'
```

So I tried using negative lookaheads in regex but couldn't figure it out..:

```
(?P<name>[\w-]+?): (?P<value>[^:]*(?![\w-]+:))\s*
```

which gave me:

```
'Start-Time', '11111.11 Content-type'
'End-Time', '22222.22'
```

It's a start, but not good enough..

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the question, then solution on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323703/regex-how-to-match-sequence-of-key-value-pairs-at-end-of-string solved my problem.